# Exporting multiple sheets using openxlsx in r

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

I am trying to make 170 sheets (3 in the code below) in one excel file using openxlsx package. I used xlsx package before and used the option "append=TRUE" to create multiple sheets in one excel file but I could not find the same option in openxlsx package.

```
system.time(
for (i in 1:3) {
write.xlsx(fulldata[[i]], file="fulltable5.xlsx", sheetName=cntry_name[i])
}
)
```

This code only creates only the third sheet. I have tried overwrite=TRUE but
this only returns error. Could you please tell me which option corresponds to "append=TRUE" in the function write.xlsx() in xlsx package?

+ADD)))

This is a data that has similar size with my original data.
It works for just one sheet but not for 172 sheets.

```
a <- list()
for (i in 1:172) {
a[[i]] <- matrix(i,30,60)
}

write.xlsx(a, file="fulltable6.xlsx")
```

And sadly, the R session is aborted.
I need 172 sheets in 1 excel file.
I am using Rstudio 3.4.0 and my computer is i3-5005U @ 2GHZ, 8gb RAM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass your (named) list to `write.xlsx`:

```
fulldata <- split(iris, seq_len(nrow(iris)) %/% 3)
names(fulldata) <- paste("sheet", seq_along(fulldata), sep="_")
library(openxlsx)
write.xlsx(fulldata, file=tf<-tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx"))
shell.exec(tf) # open file on windows
```

Comment: I tried your way and the rstudio closes saying "R Session Aborted". The there are 172 sheets with 24rows and 53 columns in each sheet.

Comment: Update your packages, R, RStudio, ...? Provide your data for testing? Cannot reproduce the error here.

Comment: @kim1298 So did you find out where the error came from?

Comment: Your code worked very well well when I tried to export few sheets. But I did not work when I tried to export 172 sheets. So I posted another question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905030/failed-to-export-excel-fine-using-xlsx-and-openxlsx-packages-in-r